Why is this PUT route not working in my Express app?
I am registering the following routes - one GET route and one PATCH route.
export default function registerNotificationRoutes(app: Express, prisma: PrismaClient) {
    app.get("/notification", verifyToken, requestedTeamAccessibleToUser, (req: Request, res: Response) => getAllNotifications(req, res, prisma));
    app.patch("/notification/:id", verifyToken, requestedTeamAccessibleToUser, (req: Request, res: Response) => markNotificationAsRead(req, res, prisma));
}

The GET route works as expected.
The PATCH route returns 404 CANNOT PATCH {route}
However, markNotificationAsRead is being called and is running.  The server terminal shows:
[1] Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[1]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:703:11)
[1]     at ServerResponse.header (/Users/home/Documents/Uni/software/comms-hub/comms-hwb-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
[1]     at ServerResponse.send (/Users/home/Documents/Uni/software/comms-hub/comms-hwb-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
[1]     at ServerResponse.json (/Users/home/Documents/Uni/software/comms-hub/comms-hwb-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
[1]     at ServerResponse.send (/Users/home/Documents/Uni/software/comms-hub/comms-hwb-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:162:21)
[1]     at /Users/home/Documents/Uni/software/comms-hub/comms-hwb-backend/src/routes/notification/controllers.ts:88:21
[1]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
[1]     at fulfilled (/Users/home/Documents/Uni/software/comms-hub/comms-hwb-backend/src/routes/notification/controllers.ts:5:58) {
[1]   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
[1] }

That usually means that res.send(foo) is being called at some point along the line without returning but the GET route has the same middleware and is not causing the same issue.  Here is the markNotificationAsRead function:
export async function markNotificationAsRead(req: Request, res: Response, prisma: PrismaClient) {
    const userId = req.userId
    const notificationId = req.params.id;
    const status = req.body.status;

    // validate payload
    if (!notificationId) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Missing value in params" });
        return;
    }

    if (!status) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Missing status in request body" });
        return;
    }

    if (status !== "READ" && status !== "UNREAD") {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid status value" });
        return;
    }

    if (!userId) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Missing userId in request" });
        return;
    }

    // get the notification and ensure that the notification belongs to the user
    const notification = await prisma.notification.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: notificationId,
            userId: userId
        }
    });

    if (!notification) {
        res.status(404).send({ message: "Notification not found" });
        return;
    }

    let updatedNotification;
    try {
        updatedNotification = await prisma.notification.update({
            where: {
                id: notificationId
            },
            data: {
                status: status
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        return;
    }

    res.status(200).send(notification);
    return;
}

The error is being triggered by the final line, suggesting the response has already been sent.
I have tried to switch the method from app.patch to app.put and app.post.  These all return the same e.g. 404 CANNOT PUT {route} and 404 CANNOT POST {route}.
I've hit the routes using Postman and get the same response.  Same issue with the headers having already been sent.  Interestingly, if I don't provide a userId / status, the if blocks in the validations section of markNotificationAsUnread are triggered and do return the expected status and JSON.
verifyToken middleware:
export default function verifyToken(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    const token = req.header('Authorization');
    if (!token) {
        console.log('no token');
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Access denied' });
        return;
    }

    const tokenString = token.split(' ')[1];

    try {
        const decoded: JwtPayload = jwt.verify(tokenString, process.env.JWT_SECRET!) as JwtPayload;
        req.userId = decoded.userId;
        req.userTeams = decoded.userTeams;
        req.authoriserFor = decoded.authoriserFor;
        if (decoded) next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid token' });
        return;
    }
};

requestedTeamAccessibleToUser middleware:
export default function requestedTeamAccessibleToUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    const requestedTeamIdParams = req.params.teamId
    const requestedTeamIdQuery = req.query.teamId
    const requestedTeamIdBody = req.body.teamId
    
    // if a specific team is not included in the request, pass to the next step.
    // the route handler logic can decide if this is acceptable.
    if (!requestedTeamIdParams && !requestedTeamIdBody && !requestedTeamIdQuery) {
        next();
    }

    const userTeamIds = req.userTeams?.map(team => team.id)

    if (requestedTeamIdParams) {
        if (!userTeamIds?.includes(requestedTeamIdParams)) {
            res.status(403).send({message: "User attempted to request resources for a team to which they don't have access."})
            return;
        }
    }

    if(requestedTeamIdQuery) {
        if (!userTeamIds?.includes(requestedTeamIdQuery)) {
            res.status(403).send({message: "User attempted to request resources for a team to which they don't have access."})
            return;
        }
    }

    if(requestedTeamIdBody) {
        if (!userTeamIds?.includes(requestedTeamIdBody)) {
            res.status(403).send({message: "User attempted to request resources for a team to which they don't have access."})
            return;
        }
    }

    // if the traps above are not triggered, the user has access to the requested team.
    next()
}

Finally, this is the frontend function which is calling the route...
function visitAndMarkAsUnread(notificationId: string, link?: string) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/notification/${notificationId}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        status: "READ"
      })
    })
      .then(() => {
        const notificationsCpy = [...notifications!]
        const notificationIndex = notificationsCpy.findIndex(notification => notification.id === notificationId)
        notificationsCpy[notificationIndex].status = "READ"
        setNotifications(notificationsCpy)
        if (link) redirect(link)
      })
  }


Your verifyToken can cause requests to stall if decoded is falsy, and requestedTeamAccessibleToUser can call a next() without returning afterwards, which can cause the ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error.

@robertklep Thank you so much!  That was driving me mad.  I had misunderstood what next() did and sort of assumed that it returned from the function magically.  :D

Does this fix all your problems? If so, I'll turn it into a proper answer :D
